# Django: Sum the count of a sub sub foreign object

Tags: django, django-models

I have many hits by Twavail
I have many Twavail for a Twaffic

I would like to sum the number of Hits for a Twaffic, and get an additionel field in Twaffic entries (hits_count), but I have some difficulties.

---

Here are my models:

```
class Twaffic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
    enchere = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Twavail(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
    twaffic = models.ForeignKey(Twaffic,editable=False,related_name='twavaux')
    tweet_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=0, editable=False)

class Hit(models.Model):
    twavail = models.ForeignKey(Twavail,editable=False,related_name='hits')
    date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=140,auto_now=True,default="")
```

I tried:

```
twaffics=Twaffic.objects.annotate(hits_count=Sum('twavaux__hits__count')).filter(user=request.user)
```

But I get the following error:

Cannot resolve keyword 'hits' into field. Choices are: twaffic, user

Is it really impossible to get this informations 2 levels ago? hits is the right related name.. Maybe I missed something?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
twaffics=Twaffic.objects.annotate(hits_count=Count('twavaux__hits')).filter(user=request.user)
```

After having added hits application to my settings.py it works, that was the big point.

Comment: Awesome...I was just looking in to queryset extra and trying it out as a problem to your solution. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Answer (score 1):

Try using this...

```
hit_count = Hit.objects.filter(twavail__id__in = Twavail.objects.filter(twaffic = twaffic_obj).values_list('id', flat=True)).count()
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused between aggregate and annotate. But I want be able to iterate on Twaffic objects, and have a additional hit_count field in the template. I think I will not be able to do so with this solution..

Comment: I made some changes in my question

Comment: Well you can use a custom template filter to calculate the hit count on the fly while iterating over the twaffic. Otherwise you can prepare a tuple of tuple like ((twaffic_obj, hit_count),…) in your view code and render it on the template

Comment: Ok, so I'm obliged to do a additional request for each Twaffic displayed in a page? Maybe I will cache the Hits foe each Twavail in a column of Twavail...

Comment: No its just behaves the way your template tag does. Look in to this... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: I know how to write templatetags, but if I use a templatetag each time I need the value for a row.. The templatetag function would be called n times, so it will request on mysql n time am I wrong?

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying now...Probably, its a good idea to cache it in that case..It would had been really good if there was a way to annotate it. I will take a look in to it let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Thx :) We are on the same line! But if I cache that value, it will be desynchronised one day, and I don't like to not be able to change values manually in the database without breaking coherency :(

Comment: I guess, to avoid doing it manually you got to do it in the Hit save method where you can update the count in the related Twavail object

Comment: Ho yes :) Thx for the idea, I had the answer under my eyes because we are talking about that, together on an other subject!

Comment: If you find a solution, I'm still interested, because I'm pretty sure I'm going to have problems in the future with a hit save method updating a field. I must also surround delete etc.. And far the more, I have the bad habbit to play with my database manually.