# Django Aggregation, sum of counts

Tags: python, sql, database, django, aggregate

I have 3 models: Forum, Thread, Post and I'm creating a view to display the list of forums. But I also want to display the number of threads and the number of posts for each forum.

I then have to:

- count the number of posts for each thread
- sum the counts of posts of each thread for each forum

I found something similar here: [Django: Sum the count of a sub sub foreign object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013333/django-sum-the-count-of-a-sub-sub-foreign-object) but the answer is not working for me.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Context
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Count

from chinwag.models import Forum, Thread, Post

@login_required
def forums(request):
    forums = Forum.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('threads__posts')).all(
            ).select_related('threads__last_post')
    return render(request, 'chinwag/forums.html', Context({
        'forums': forums,
    }))
```

Is it possible to do it in 1 SQL query? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use

```
Forum.objects.annotate(num_threads=Count('threads__id'),
                       num_posts=Count('threads__posts__id'))
```

This makes two annotations in one database hit.

The first counts all threads on the forum, the second counts all posts on all threads of the forum (assuming a `thread` as a ForeignKey with `Form`, and a `post` a `ForeignKey` with `threads`.

The exact naming in `'threads__posts__id'` depends on the name of the foreign key, but Django will spit an error with suggestions if they are not correct.

P.S. you can remove `.all()`, it is not doing anything.